# How to do ToInt32(string) on Micro Framework?

Tags: c#, .net-micro-framework, netduino

Sorry for the noob question... C# is new to me.

(And reaching for basic stuff in the framework and finding it missing is a little disorienting.)

The question:

On the 4.1 .NET Micro Framework, how do I implement ToInt32(string), since the native .net micro framework lacks these conversion functions?

Thank you !

Comment: does it have int.parse and int.tryparse? That's what you would normally use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .NET Micro Framework (at least, version 3.0 and above) has an `Int32.Parse` method which will do what you want: convert a string representation of a number into the actual integer equivalent.

The documentation for that method is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd187967.aspx).

Call it like this:

```
String myString = "100";
Int32 myNumber = Int32.Parse(myString);
```

But it looks like the .NET Micro Framework (again, version 3.0 and above) also provides the [`Convert` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd169375.aspx), including various overloads of methods such as [`ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd188073.aspx) and [`ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd188068.aspx), so I'm not really sure what the problem is and why you say that it "lacks these conversion functions". Which ones are missing?

Comment: Well, there is System.Int32.Parse .... Don't know why that is there and ToInt32 isn't.... but it works!